# How to make @Repository work?

Tags: java, spring-3, spring-annotations

I can't figure out why autowiring doesn't work as it should. I've a non-web application which uses spring 3 and so in the application's main method I've set to create the application context like this:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                        DEFAULT_APP_CONTEXT);
```

And the `.xml` file has at the top the needed stuff for autowiring to work:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="star,hw" />
```

However it doesn't work. I've a service class with a class level `@Repository` annotation under `hw` package, but when trying to `@Autowire` it I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'inventoryDAO' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 77 more
```

One weird thing i noticed in the log file:

```
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4440ece0: defining beans [*skipping*, inventoryDAOImpl, *skipping*]
```

That is the class I've `@Repository` used on, but it implements `InventoryDAO`. Isn't that wrong that it shows there `inventoryDAOImpl`? What can I do to figure out what's wrong?

Edit: Okay, probably the problem isn't in `@Autowire` but in `@Repository` for not making the bean correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@Repository("inventoryDAO")`.

Comment: Ouch, that did the trick! Why? :o I've a web application where I'm using `@Repository` without having to write anything in it.

Comment: If you are using autowiring-by-name in any form, then the bean name defaults to the classname (with the first letter downcased). So the bean name in your case was inventoryDaoImpl. With autowiring-by-type you shouldn't have to specify a name as long as your DAO is the only one on the app context (which is usually the case with DAOs).

Comment: Wasn't @Autowire by type by default? How to autowire-by-type? I've just added pure `@Autowire` to the field in service class to autowire the DAO.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for both the repo bean and the target bean?

Comment: Sorry, repo bean and target bean?

Comment: The bean with the @Repository annotation, and the bean you're injecting it into. I want to see how you have it set up.

Comment: Nothing extraordinary. The target bean is just a class like: `UserServiceImpl` which implements `UserService` with `@Component` annotation. The injected repo bean is `UserDAOImpl` which implements `UserDAO`. The weird thing is the same stuff in one project where it works without having to specify anything in the @Repository annotation, however it doesn't work in the other one and I need to specify the name of the bean there which sucks to do so.